# Lambda function has high invocation time if not being frequently invoked

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-xray, cold-start

I wonder if someone help me to understand Lambda Xray tracing please?

I have a Lambda function with cold start as below. As you can see, theres 699ms cold start. But what I don't understand why it also has high invocation duration. If I repeatedly invoke the function, the invocation duration will always be around 200-300ms.

[image: with cold start]

I did another experiment when the Lambda function is still warm but not frequently invoked. Basically, I waited for 1 min before invoke the function again. The results showed the Lambda function had high invocation duration as well

[image: without cold start]

This is very strange. I wonder what is included in the invocation time in xray tracing?

Comment: I highly doubt this behaviour is related to lambda cold start issue. I suspect it's related to the logic of your function.

Comment: I wouldnt think so. I did load testing and the p95 is around 320ms, p99 600ms, median 170ms

Comment: so i increased the memory from 128 mb to 256 mb. It seems the performance is better and more consistent now. However, i dont see much changes in CPU usage in Lambda Insights.

Comment: when using 128 mb , the memory usage is 90%. Meanwhile, when using 256 mb, memory usage is 50%. Would memory affect processing speed?

Comment: @MinhNguyen, yes memory would affect processing speed since you would have more CPU: see the doc here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-memory-console